# Why does Resources.Load<GameObject>() not consistently work? Returns a object is null error as well. Unity 2021 LTS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources, gameobject

I have a dictionary:  `Dictionary<string,string> prefabPaths`.  This prefab paths is a simple key,value that stores a filepath to prefabs that I have already created in Unity.  To test this,  I have a for loop that iterates through the dictionary and performs `Resources.Load<GameObject>(value)`.  The first three are loaded as they should; the rest do not load.

For more context that could matter:  trying to load `enemyP` or my other test prefab return an error of the object you are trying to instantiate is null.

Here is my Debug.Log snip:
[Snip of Unity Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbVZb.png)

You can see the key,value as well as the value again separately.
Further evidence that the paths are getting stored in the dictionary correctly is I made a list that gets each value form the dictionary:
[Snip of Unity List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Darpv.png)

Here is a snip of how the prefabs appear in the folder structure:
[Snip of prefabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuJYx.png)

This Prefabs folder is obviously nested in Assets/Resources.  Both prefabs are in the same folder. However, the three that try to load enemyP do nothing:
[Evidence of it not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uShMt.png)

Am I missing something here?  They are both prefabs.  They exist in the same folder.  I used the correct names on both.

```
foreach (var c in dictPrefabs)
            {
                prefabsDict.Add(c.Value);
                prefabs.Add(Resources.Load<GameObject>(c.Value));
                Debug.Log(c + "    " + c.Value);
            }
```

`prefabsDict` is just a test List that is used for this exact testing to make sure the paths were being pulled correctly and I could see them in the Unity Inspector.

I also tried casting as just an `Object` instead of `GameObject`.  That did not work either even though, again, `p3pmc` gets loaded just fine.  I've tested this on another prefab as well that is not working either.

Any help would be appreciated.  I am getting very upset about this.  I do not like it when things do and do not work like this.  I have read other threads here and abroad the internet with no solution found as to why this is not working.

Comment: Check that your value and the prefab name do not have a space at the beginning or end that we cannot see.

Comment: I agree with @hijinxbassist. A trailing whitespace will do that. Resources.Load just returns null if the path is wrong, it doesn't error out.

Comment: Unfortunately, both recommendations were not the problem.  The issue was that on my laptop - the Unity project was somehow corrupt with how it was seeing files.  There was no issue at all on my desktop.  Looks like a full delete and Plastic sync of the project is required.  It could also be corruption within Unity 2021.3.19f as well. Thanks for the comments, though!